# ObjectValidator unit testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, validation, enterprise

I'm having problems with [ObjectValidator]. So, i have:

```
public class UserBO
{
    public int ID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [NotNullValidator(MessageTemplate = "Can't be null!")]
    [RegexValidator(@"[a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]*", MessageTemplate = "Must be valid!", Ruleset = "validate_username")]
    [StringLengthValidator(5, RangeBoundaryType.Inclusive, 25, RangeBoundaryType.Inclusive,  Ruleset = "validate_username")]
    public string username
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

and another class:

```
public class PersonBO
{
    public int ID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [NotNullValidator(MessageTemplate="Can't be null!")]
    [ObjectValidator(MessageTemplate = "Must be valid!", Ruleset="validate_obj_user")]
    public UserBO User
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
...
```

Now can you tell me why the following test passes?

```
[TestMethod()]
public void PersonBOConstructorTest()
    {
        PersonBO target = new PersonBO()
            {
                User = new UserBO
                {
                    ID = 4,
                    username = "asd"
                }
            };
        ValidationResults vr = Validation.Validate<PersonBO>(target, "validate_obj_user");
        Assert.IsTrue(vr.IsValid);
    }
```

This should not be valid, because: User attribute (of UserBO type) contains username "asd" (3 characters), and i defined for it a StringLengthValidator (between 5 and 25 characters).. so why the test passes? that object is not valid
I can't understand.

Thanks.

Comment: While it isn't really germane to your actual question, both the regex and string length validators will choke on a null.  That means the not-null validator is redundant.

Comment: And again, while it isn't germane to your question, the regex "[a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]*" probably isn't doing what you think it's doing. Literally, every possible string will pass the check. I suspect that "^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,25}$" is probably closer to what you want. Assuming what you want is to ensure usernames have nothing but letters and numbers. That also has the advantage of covering the string length check, getting you down to only one validator.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify a ruleset in your ObjectValidator if you want rules from a set other than the default set applied.

```
[ObjectValidator("validate_username", MessageTemplate = "Must be valid!", Ruleset = "validate_obj_user")]
```

The above should work in this specific case.  Alternatively, you could remove the ruleset parameter from the string length validator to leave it in the default set.